# Linux command line song Identification software

Tags: linux, command-line, music-recognition

Requirements

- Linux
- Command line based
- Interpenetrated song recognition (matching a song like shazam does not bit for bit)
- Returns metadata about the song like artist and album

Like to have features

- Able to choose what data is given
- Standard command line output

Any other suggestions on features are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`pyacoustid`](https://github.com/sampsyo/pyacoustid) library, particularly the `aidmatch.py` script.

Example usage:

```
$ python3 /usr/share/doc/python-acoustid/examples/aidmatch.py 01.\ Dominium\ Maris\ Baltici.ogg
Sabaton - Dominium maris Baltici
http://musicbrainz.org/recording/1473c9e0-bf39-4c96-8c46-b692df220873
Score: 92%
```

It uses the [AcoustID](https://acoustid.org/) API, so you will require an internet connection.