# What music id software can add track names to my songs?

Tags: file-management, music-recognition

I have about 200 songs on my computer (.WAV files, but I can convert them if necessary).

They are named S-1, S-2, ... S-200.

They have no meta info except the track number.

Is there software than can identify the song and add the song info to the file? Best case scenario, it renames the file to the name of the song.

I know Shazam and many other apps can identify a song. But I can't find one that will rename the file for me as well. I also found that iTunes can add song titles to tracks, but I have a few problems with that. I use Windows, and the times I've tried iTunes, it was a nightmare. Most of my music was recorded with Audacity, and from what I know, it has to be ripped from a CD for iTunes to get the track info. I also read these questions and answers but didn't find what I was looking for:

- [Web app for music identification which can be used on PC](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46636/web-app-for-music-identification-which-can-be-used-on-pc)
- [Software to accurately identify unknown songs without words?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/41961/software-to-accurately-identify-unknown-songs-without-words)
- [Linux command line song Identification software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36395/linux-command-line-song-identification-software) (this one is especially similar to my question, and I have linux available. I would go down this avenue if it were not a dead end.)

Must haves:

- Works on Windows.
- I don't have to play the whole song.
- The sound file gets renamed or gets updated meta info with the song name.
- Requires no manual effort for each track (no skipping to the next song manually, no typing track names, set up once and do all tracks together)

But if that doesn't exist, I'd like to know of anything related that could help me name these songs.

Comment: Currently attempting beets.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beet definitely has all the features I'm looking for. But, my use case is not a perfect fit. First I had to convert my WAV files to FLAC files (which I accomplished using Audacity). WAV files don't support metadata very well. Then I had to put each song file into individual *album* folders. Each song just needs to be in a separate folder. Then I was ready to use beet.

Beet didn't work 'out of the box' for this. I had to set up one plugin - Chromaprint/AcousticId plugin. The documentation was very helpful and all the dependencies work on Windows nicely. It was a little tricky to add some things to my PATH variable, namely, moving the `fpcalc.exe` to the correct folder (I created a folder `~/AppData/Roaming/Chromaprint/` and used that in my user PATH variable).

But then, it was like magic. This was a great solution. During the set up, I bumped into other similar projects, but I didn't end up needing them or trying them. But I will list them just for anyone's curiosity (9 page views in its 25 days of existence hahaha why do I think anyone will ever read this ahahah):

- [Python Audio Tools](http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/) for converting audio formats, renaming, changing metadata.
- [Metabrainz Picard](https://github.com/metabrainz/picard) for using acoustic id to get song metadata.

Comment: I'm reading this :-)